# Errors installing node-sass in Angular 6 project

Tags: node.js, angular, sass, node-sass

I've cloned a repo from an existing Angular 6 project and executed `npm install`. After a bunch of warnings about deprecated packages (not unexpected, given that the project was created several years ago using Angular 6), I get a bunch of errors:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/.../node_modules/ng-packagr/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh /var/folders/xx/41k1bd6j11j5zh2vl572rg0m0000gn/T/postinstall-e6df27d4.sh
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node /Users/.../node_modules/ng-packagr/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR!
```

Etc...

*Notably, node-sass is not listed in `package.json` as a dependency.*

My version of **npm** is **8.15.0** and **node** is **v16.17.0**.

For what it's worth - I have **python 2.7.18** installed.

I've read here that node-sass has been deprecated, and I should replace it with **sass**, however, since it's not listed in `package.json`, I don't know how to do that.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Angular 6` using `node v16` might be causing the problem. Please refer this table for `Angular CLI ~ Angular ~ Node` computability versions

[Angular Compatibility Matrix](https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3)

So according to this your local versions should be

- Angular Cli - 6.0.8
- Node - 8.9.4